# Error message "The format of the file is invalid" when attempting to import certificate on HP printer

Tags: openssl, hp, certificate, network-printer

On some HP printers, when I try to import a certificate to enable HTTPS for the printer's Embedded Web Server (EWS), I get the error message "The format of the file is invalid". This happens both (1) when I have created the CSR using openssl and (2) when I use the "Create a Certificate Request" option in EWS.

Updating to the latest firmware does not help.

Example model: HP Color LaserJet MFP M477fnw

[image: Embedded Web Server Networking tab, Certificates pane showing error message "The format of the file is invalid"]

Answer (score 0):

This failure occurs when the certificate file includes the full certificate chain to the root certificate. Apparently, the affected printers cannot process a chain of root and intermediate certificates.

When you submit your certificate signing request (CSR) to your certificate authority (CA), whether that be internal PKI or a commercial CA, request that it omit the certificate chain from the certificate. Then the printer will be able to successfully import it.

I suspect that it might be possible to remove the certificate chain using a tool like openssl (so you wouldn't have to make a special request to your CA), but that is beyond my expertise.

Comment: There is a recent firmware with fix to this bug.